# Wörterbücher zu norddeutschen Dialekten

Tags: dialect, resource, dictionary, northern-german

Diese Woche las ich in dem gut gemachten, und auch lustigen [Buch von Jürgen Meyer *Wat is - Is wat? Das Ruhrstadt-Wörterbuch*](http://www.buecher.de/shop/buecher/wat-is-is-wat/meyer-juergen/products_products/detail/prod_id/23391106/). Kann jemand ähnliche Bücher für norddeutsche Dialekte empfehlen?

Comment: Kannst du, für Leute, die dieses _Ruhrstadt-Wörterbuch_ nicht kennen, es näher beschreiben? Aus „lustig“ schließe ich schon einmal, daß du eher nicht an einem der wissenschaftlichen Wörterbücher interessiert bist.

Answer (score 3):

Für den hamburgischen Dialekt/Missingsch kann ich das Buch von Peter Schmachthagen: "Sprechen Sie Hamburgisch?" vom Hamburger Abendblatt (Axel Springer Verlag) empfehlen. ([Das Buch bei Amazon.de](http://www.amazon.de/Sprechen-Hamburgisch-Allerlei-Begriffe-Gro%C3%9Fmutter/dp/393971626X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1448445997&sr=1-1&keywords=Missingsch), wahrscheinlich am besten gebraucht erhältlich).

Es ist sehr unterhaltsam geschrieben und enthält zu den Erklärungen viele spannende Anekdoten.
Ich nehme an, dass das Ruhrstadt-Wörterbuch ähnlich gestaltet sein könnte.

Für Schleswig-Holsteinische Dialekte gibt es vom shz-Verlag [eine Sammlung mit dem Titel "So spricht Schleswig-Holstein"](http://www.shzshop.de/epages/es80570.sf/de_DE/?ObjectPath=/Shops/es80570/Products/163901/SubProducts/SHZ001-0002), die habe ich aber selbst noch nicht gelesen. Vielleicht hilft es dir aber als Pointer in die richtige Richtung zu dem, was du suchst.

Comment: Vielen Dank für diese schönen Hinweise!